# How to choose the text editor to open a file?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, how can I choose the text editor to open a file?

For example, a text file ending with ".xml" is treated as an XML file and shown with a color scheme (e.g. keys in light blue and values in orange), but how can a text file not ending with ".xml" is treated as an XML file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[VS Code Docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview#_changing-the-language-for-the-selected-file):

> In VS Code, we default the language support for a file based on its
> filename extension. However, at times you may wish to change language
> modes, to do this click on the language indicator - which is located
> on the right hand of the Status Bar. This will bring up the Select
> Language Mode drop-down where you can select another language for the
> current file.
>
> [image: Blockquote]
>
> Tip: You can get the same drop-down by running the Change Language Mode command (⌘K M).

You can also add a custom mapping for extensions:

> You can add new file extensions to an existing language with the files.associations setting. For example, the setting below adds the .myphp file extension to the php language identifier:
>
> ```
>  "files.associations": {
>    "*.myphp": "php"
>  }
> ```

Answer (score 2):

To change the used language when you open a file with a particular extension use a setting

```
  "files.associations": {
    "*.xyz": "xml"
  },
```